# How to use variables as key of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I'm very new at python so asking for forgiveness if I'm asking very stupid question. So, I have this dictionary called array with some value, now I want to input the key as a variable and use that to print value assigned to that key.

```
array = {'color':'blue' , 'size':'small'}
print array ['color']
```

this works just fine, outputting the value blue. but if I try this it doesn't work.

```
array = {'color':'blue' , 'size':'small'}
var = input ('input a key') #input would be " color " or " size "
print array[var]
```

I think there is a very easy solution to this. thanks for helping in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Your input has leading and trailing whitespace. For example, `' color '` is not the same as `'color'`. Your dictionary has no key `' color '`. You can `strip` the whitespace from an input string like this:

```
>>> mydict = {'color':'blue' , 'size':'small'}
>>> var = input().strip()
' color '
>>> mydict[var]
'blue'
```

By the way, your `array` is a Python dictionary, calling it array is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the mis understanding, i used the " " and spaces to make sure that those are infact keys im inputting. i didnt use the spaces it was plain color no spaces.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid KeyError exception, you can use get:

```
>>> mydict = {'color':'blue' , 'size':'small'}
>>> var = input().strip()
' color '
>>> mydict.get(var, 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i finaly got it to working :)

```
mydict = {'color':'blue' , 'size':'small'}
var =str( raw_input ('input a key'))
print mydict[var]
```

seems all i needed was to get raw input and convert it to string